# align html elements one after the other

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two dropdown lists in the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lojadofaqe/edit?html,css,output) below. How can I align them one after the other, and align them towards the center of the page, with sufficient space between the two html elements, without hardcoding spaces, using

Also, my bootstrap jumbotron header doesn't span the entire page.
I have tried to do it using the following, however, it still leaves a space at the left.

```
<div class="jumbotron" style="width: 1600px;">
```

EDIT : I have tried the code changes suggested below. I am able to get the jumbotron to be full width now, however, the dropdownlists are quite different to what I see in your jsbins. Please see screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following JSBin: http://jsbin.com/tapuviyoja/1/edit?html,css,output

I am not sure what you mean by align after one another. Do you mean inline or on the next line? If you want inline then you need to remove the `<br>` between the two select elements and `display: inline-block;`.

Your Jumbotron doesn't extend the full width because its `container` has some padding as well. Remove the padding and set the width of the container and the jumbotron to 100%;

In order to get the form to align center, you need to increase the width of it to 100% of the window and then `text-align:center` it.

```
.line{
width:33%;
float:left;
}

.jumbotron {
 padding-top: 0%;
 padding-bottom: 0%;
 width:100%;
}

.container{
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZQXod-TpW5bx9oSysCVEdpsYS_9ssKwfbS04asZ2L9xzSnOiHdhFWxFS9') no-repeat center center;
  /*opacity: 0.2;*/
  background-size: cover;
}

form{
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
}

form select{
 display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: @A. Sharma, thanks. I still have a problem with the alignment. Please see the edit above

Comment: Make the form width **100%**. See my CSS code above for the `form`. You can really just copy the code from my JSBin I presented.

Comment: thanks. I was following your code, but I had accidentally placed an echo "</br>"; between the two drop down lists, which was causing the positioning to be as in the image in edit. I had only used your CSS code, and kept my HTML code as is. Changed it, and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `<form>` this way works:

```
<form method="get" action="index.php" style="text-align: center;">
```

Or in CSS, add:

```css
form {text-align: center;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap the `form` inside a wrapper `div.`

Then, set the `display` property on the `form` to `inline-block`, which makes it react to the `text-align: center` property on the parent `.wrapper` element. Finally, set the `text-align` property on the `form` to `left` so that child `inline` and `inline-block` elements don't get centered.

HTML

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
      ...
    </form>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

DEMO http://jsbin.com/medanexipo/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

The below should sort out your issues. There were also problems with the structure of your html. For instance there are div's in your head and some other issues.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRZQXod-TpW5bx9oSysCVEdpsYS_9ssKwfbS04asZ2L9xzSnOiHdhFWxFS9') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  padding: 0
}
.jumbotron {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
form {
  text-align: center
}
select {
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <h1 align="center" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS">Check Near You</></h1>
      <p align="center" style="font-family:Comic Sans MS">See which articles are near you ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form method="get" action="index.php">
    <select class="language" name="language">
      <option value="tagalog">Tagalog</option>
      <option value="english">English</option>
    </select>


    <select class="year" name="year">
      <option value="2010">2010</option>
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2012">2012</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
      <option value="2016">2016</option>
      <option value="2017">2017</option>
      <option value="2018">2018</option>
      <option value="2019">2019</option>
      <option value="2020">2020</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @JustinChew, thanks. The alignment still looks a bit different for me, from your jsbin. Please see the edit above

Comment: @JustinChew, thanks Justin. Your solution worked fine, I had accidentally placed an echo "</br>"l between my two drop down lists in html